# PowerBI Parent-child hierarchies

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I am following this example to represent a hierarchy.

First step, I'm trying to create a column
EntityPath = PATH ( Entity[EntityKey], Entity[ParentEntityKey] )

Their example is as follows:

[image]

My example is however slightly different,
[image]

I split the Parent column by last > and then trimmed and cleaned it. However, reusing the same dax as above returned the following error:

"The value 'EC.1' in 'Table'[Reference] must also exist in 'Table'[ParentEntityKey]. Please add the missing data and try again."

I got to this point:

[image]

And am getting the following error:

The value '' in 'Table'[ParentEntityKey] must also exist in 'Table'[EntityKey]. Please add the missing data and try again.

I believe what it's referring to is the very top level. The top level doesn't have a parent. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you share a sample .pbix?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a wild guess, the cell in `ParentEntityKey` perhaps contains a zero-length string instead of an actual blank. Try to replace `""` with `null` in Power Query, reload the table and retry your DAX code.